# Privacy Url and platform info to get permission for Facebook app

Tags: windows, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a Windows app for my personal use in visual studio in asp. Net  .I don't want to register this app to Windows store and i don't have any Privacy policy.But Facebook is not giving required permission .Is there any way to Get required permission with out platform info and Privacy policy

Comment: _“But Facebook is not giving required permission”_ – what do you mean by that - login review? You don’t need to get your app reviewed, if you are only going to use it yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: i trying to login to fb through my app but  its showing that **'Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings'**

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a windows app to Facebook login.But it wants my app domain . But its my locally hosted windows app what will be my ddomain? And facebook has depicted localhost domain.then now what to do?